# Convert file path to full URL with Express

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a Node.js backend code write with express.

I upload pictures and save it in a folder. I save the absolute path of this file in database.

I would like to know how I can transform the absolute path to a correct URL with host name, eventually a port. Can I do it with express ?

Example :

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,
    "data": {
        "id": "5e0deb6dfe82df845fd04d88",
        "url": ==> Here I want the protocol, hostname and port <=="/api/picture/5da78ac350d5deec229ecf09ef7497fc"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose or use case for this? Host names could technically change over time. For example if you have multiple domains pointing to the same IP address for this server.

Comment: It's just a simple REST API, when I want to retrieve information from a specific user, for example I prefer to get the direct link to his profile picture

Answer (score 1):

[`req.hostname`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.hostname) contains the URL information.

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,
    "data": {
        "id": "5e0deb6dfe82df845fd04d88",
        "url": req.hostname + "/api/picture/5da78ac350d5deec229ecf09ef7497fc"
    }
}
```

Comment: Important to note that this is just the same as the `Host` header value. So technically it's not guaranteed to exist.